# Can i send json data to Mithril route from outside

Tags: routes, mithril.js

For example i have next mitril routes.

```js
m.route.prefix("#");
m.route(document.getElementById('main'), "/", {
"/": {
 render: function() {
  return m('h1','Hello from root');
 }
},
"/trackingController/:numbers": {
 render: function(data) {
  var data = JSON.parse("data");
  // then work with parsed data
  return m('h1', 'Hello from trackingController')
 }
}
```

Can i send json data to trackingController route from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, routes can interpolate parameters. In your example you have a `:numbers` parameter, and your code suggests you expect a JSON string.

The way Mithril exposes data passed through entities is via [the `vnode` interface](https://mithril.js.org/vnodes.html#basics)'s `attrs` property. In the case of route components and route resolvers (like you're using here), [`attrs` is a map of the URL parameters](https://mithril.js.org/route.html#routeresolverrender).

In this example I'm using `encodeURIComponent` to allow JSON to be introduced in the URL. I've made the render function log the parsed data received from the URI path and expose the current route, as well as a text box where you can edit the JSON structure and submit it to re-route and see the new results.

```js
m.route.prefix("#");
m.route(document.getElementById('main'), "/trackingController/" + encodeURIComponent('[1,2]'), {
  "/trackingController/:numbers": {
    render: function(vnode) {
      console.log(
        'Received the following `numbers`:',
        JSON.parse(vnode.attrs.numbers)
      )

      return [
        m('h1', 'Hello from trackingController'),

        m('p', 'Current route is ',
          m('code', m.route.get())
        ),

        m('form', {
            onsubmit: function(e) {
              e.preventDefault()

              m.route.set(
                "/trackingController/" +
                encodeURIComponent(e.target.elements.input.value)
              )
            }
          },
          m('textarea#input', {
            value: vnode.attrs.numbers,
            style: {
              background: '#444',
              color: '#eee',
              display: 'block',
              padding: '1em',
            },
          }),

          m('button', 'Go!')
        ),
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>
<div id=main></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful.